# Equivalent condition on symmetry of product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

This is not homework, but rather a problem I found in the practice problems for application to a Master in Mathematics. I have been unsuccessful to solve it and would appreciate any hint. Here it is

Let $A,B,C,D$ be square matrices. Show that the following two conditions are equivalent:

1. $AB^T$ and $CD^T$ are symmetric and $AD^T-BC^T=Id;$
2. $B^TD$ and $A^TC$ are symmetric and $A^TD-C^TB=Id$.

I have tried to manipulate this equations and virtually get nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* The first condition says that
$$
\pmatrix{A&-B\\ -C&D}\pmatrix{D^T&B^T\\ C^T&A^T}=I.
$$